# ASP.NET EditorTemplate DropdownList

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, editortemplates

**Every time I add a new App It creates a new AppCategory**. I am seriously screwing this up somehow

code first entity framework objects

```
public class AppCategory
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<App> apps { get; set; }
}

public class App 
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public AppCategory Category { get; set; }
}
```

Editor Template (I would love to just make just one Foreign Key EditorTemplate)

```
@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage
@Html.DropDownList("Category", LIG2010RedesignMVC3.Models.Repo.GetAppCategoriesSelect())
```

and of course the repository

```
    public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetAppCategoriesSelect()
    {
        return (from p in GetAppCategories()
                select new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = p.Name,
                    Value = p.ID.ToString(),

                });
    }


    public static ICollection<AppCategory> GetAppCategories()
    {
        var context = new LIGDataContext();
        return context.AppCategories.ToList();
    }
```

Every time I add a new App It creates a new AppCategory  I am seriously screwing this up somehow

---

**Adding more debug info**

```
 @inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage
 @Html.DropDownList("", LIG2010RedesignMVC3.Models.Repo.GetAppCategoriesSelect())
```

gives me a validation message on the post

```
 Parameters  application/x-www-form-urlencoded
 Category   1
 Name   8
```

Validation error **The value '1' is invalid.**
This makes sense because Category should be an object not an integer.

---

**Controller Code as asked for** 
pretty sure this isnt the problem as it came from MVCScaffold

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(App d)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
          context.Apps.Add(d);
          context.SaveChanges();
          return RedirectToAction("Index");  
        }
        return View();
     }
```

Comment: I have no idea what your question is or how you got an upvote for article.  Have you stepped through the program in a debugger to narrow down where whatever your problem is occurs?

Comment: from the controller [HttpPost] public ActionResult Create(App d)    I get d.Category is null (thats why its creating a new one) but i dont know why i get d.Category is null

Comment: Post your controller code please.  I'm fairly certain the problem is there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My model was incorrectly set up ... virtual ICollection and just the foreign key id for the sub and everything worked...  changes below

Model

```
public class AppCategory
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public **virtual** ICollection<App> Apps { get; set; }
}

public class App 
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    ********************************************
    [UIHint("AppCategory")]
    public int AppCategoryID { get; set; }
    ********************************************
    public string Name { get; set; }

}

public class LIGDataContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<AppCategory> AppCategories { get; set; }
    public DbSet<App> Apps { get; set; } 
}
```

/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/AppCategory.cshtml

```
@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage
@Html.DropDownList("", LIG2010RedesignMVC3.Models.Repo.GetAppCategoriesSelect())
```

AppController

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(App d)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
          this.repository.Add(d);
          this.repository.Save();
          return RedirectToAction("Index");  
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you bind your dropDownList to Category.Id, you'll at least get the selected value into that filed, but nothing else in your Category Object.

Comment: It still tries to create a new Category object

Answer (score 0):

The model binder cannot create the `AppCategory` object from the form collection in your `Create` action because the form only has an ID for that object (the other properties of `AppCategory` are not there).

The quickest solution would be setting the `Category` property of your `App` object manually, like this :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(App d) {
    int categoryId = 0;
    if (!int.TryParse(Request.Form["Category"] ?? String.Empty, out categoryId) {
        // the posted category ID is not valid
        ModelState.AddModelError("Category", 
            "Please select a valid app category.")
    } else {
        // I'm assuming there's a method to get an AppCategory by ID.
        AppCategory c = context.GetAppCategory(categoryID);
        if (c == null) {
            // couldn't find the AppCategory with the given ID.
            ModelState.AddModelError("Category", 
                "The selected app category does not exist.")
        } else {
            // set the category of the new App.
            d.Category = c;
        }
    }
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
      context.Apps.Add(d);
      context.SaveChanges();
      return RedirectToAction("Index");  
    }
    return View();
 }
```